# Your computer appears to be correctly configured, but the device or resource (DNS server) is not responding message in window 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, dns, connection

I have tried most of the solutions like flush dns, release, renew, Winsock reset, configuring IP automatically.
I am connected to the wifi tried updating reinstalling its adapter still doesn't work.

Comment: Like the message says, your DNS provider is not responding, for whatever reason. There's nothing you can do locally to fix that, except to change your DNS provider, if possible. Even that may not work if it's your ISP interfering with your computer's DNS requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try [changing the DNS server you're using](https://1.1.1.1/dns/)

1. Click on the Start menu, then click on Control Panel.
2. Click on Network and Internet.
3. Click on Change Adapter Settings.
4. Right click on the Wi-Fi network you are connected to, then click Properties.
5. Select Internet Protocol Version 4 (or Version 6 if desired).
6. Click Properties.
7. Write down any existing DNS server entries for future reference.
8. Click Use The Following DNS Server Addresses.
9. Replace those addresses with the 1.1.1.1 DNS addresses:

   For IPv4: 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1
   For IPv6: 2606:4700:4700::1111 and 2606:4700:4700::1001
10. Click OK, then Close.

It's then a good idea to restart your computer.

Comment: I tried your method still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Are you using / have you used any VPN using IKEv2 encryption?
The IKEv2 adapter or the VPN client itself can make some troubles with the pc network.
Another thing maybe that a specific software is entangling with the pc network. Try disabling or uninstalling the programs you have lately installed.
Or it is just some router problem... always try rebooting router (unplug/replug).

Comment: I once installed VPN but it didn't connect.  I don't know which software is that. I once format my OS does it have to do  anything